# Woocommerce: Is it possible to change the price of a product automatically based on the price of another product?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I was wondering if it is possible to 'bind' the prices of different products a and b in Woocommerce, so the price of product b will change automatically when the price of product a is manually changed. (the two products should always have the same price). Could I even write a script for something like that? If so, could it also work with variations of products?

Extra info: I read into the Dynamic Pricing plugin but from what I understand it is used for different purposes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this, I guess?

```php
add_action( 'updated_post_meta', 'bind_product_prices', 10, 4 );
function bind_product_prices( $meta_id, $post_id, $meta_key, $meta_value ) {
    $product_a_id = 21;
    $product_b_id = 33;
    
    if ( $post_id !== $product_a_id && $post_id !== $product_b_id ) {
        return;
    }
    
    if ( $meta_key !== '_regular_price' ) {
        return;
    }
    
    $new_price = floatval( $meta_value );
    
    if ( $post_id == $product_a_id ) {
        $product_b = wc_get_product( $product_b_id );
        $product_b_price = (float) $product_b->get_regular_price();
                
        if ( $product_b_price === $new_price ) {
            return;
        }
        
        $product_b->set_regular_price( $new_price );
        $product_b->save();
    }
    
    if ( $post_id == $product_b_id ) {
        $product_a = wc_get_product( $product_a_id );
        $product_a_price = (float) $product_a->get_regular_price();
        
        if ( $product_a_price === $new_price ) {
            return;
        }
        
        $product_a->set_regular_price( $new_price );
        $product_a->save();
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried your code using snippets and it worked as intended! I want to bind a few hundred products like this, I will try to make vectors or matrices for it. Do you have any other suggestions for it?